# Get cell value but skip row if wrong

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables:

[image]

I want to get all names from Table 1 that have status "Denied". I tried using IF formula but it returns blank/other false value. Expected result is Table 3.

Is there any other formula that can solve this?

Comment: Does filtering not meet your requirements?

Comment: The problem is the result still include false row. Expected result is only show true rows automatically. My current condition is using "if" formula and the result is table 2 that include false row

Comment: Although this could be done using formulas, have you looked into PowerQuery? It's created for this exact purpose and would give you exactly what you want... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula in Table 3 Column 1
`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$15="Denied"),$A$2:$A$15,""),ROW()-2),"")`

Note: Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after putting in the formula (As it is an array formula)
No need for a second table

Use this formula in Table 3 Column 2
`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$11,MATCH(E3,$A$3:$A$11,0)),"")`

Use this formula in Table 3 Column 3
`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$11,MATCH(E3,$A$3:$A$11,0)),"")`

[image: Have a look at this screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your example. I'm trying to custom your formula, I still don't understand which function exclude false value. I don't need to show "No" column, only name and date.