# skip if statement is false in excel mac

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently working on a database (that's why I needed to blur some cells.) and I want to copy some data from the first sheet according to the graduation status. We are planning to use this database for next years too, so I want it to copy the data automatically when someone adds information. I wrote a formula for this, it is copying the data as I want but it cant skip the false condition; as it can be seen, the 8-9-16-17th row in General Sheet is copied to Student Sheet.

I saw another problem like mine and tried to implement the formula in my sheet but I couldn't make it work.

The problem that another person was dealing with: [Get cell value but skip row if wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471645/get-cell-value-but-skip-row-if-wrong)

The formula I found and tried to implement in my Excel book: =IFERROR(SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$15="Denied"),$A$2:$A$15,""),ROW()-2),"")

The formula I used in my Excel book: =IF(GENERAL!E3 = "Student";Table1[@Name];"")

[image: I couldn't managed to add 2 images here so I combined two excel page screenshot in one image. I hope I expressed myself clearly, Thank you all in advance :)]

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 365 you can use the Filter() function. In the sreenshot I used

```
=FILTER(A:C,B:B="student")
```

[image]

Be aware, though, that with any formula solution, the result will be dynamically recalculated, so if you are planning on adding any data to the filtered table, these manual data entries will become a problem when the formula updates and the previous results occupy different positions.

If your goal is to get a one-time copy of all the non-graduated Students in Sheet A, you could just sort the sheet by the status column and copy/paste the desired data into a new sheet. That pasted data will not change and you can make manual edits.

Comment: I have tried but couldnt manage to make It work. I wrote the same formula but it filled every cell with #VALUE!. 

I try to change some things in the formula and got different results. It either copied just students (still with blank rows), or every cell filled with #VALUE! or #SPILL!, or it also copied the datas I need but filled the blank rows with #VALUE! or #SPILL!

Comment: OK, if you get the #Spill! error, that means you do have the correct version of Excel. That is good. Go to the Student Sheet and in cell A2 put this formula `=FILTER(general!A:H,general!E:E="student")` I have tested this with some sample data and it works. You only need the formula in cell A2. It will automatically spill into all required cells. If you get the #SPILL! error, that means that there is stuff in the cells where the formula wants to put results, so make sure that all cells below and to the right of A2 are empty